# Scaffold-DbContext Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core

```
Scaffold-DbContext "DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/@ORCLPDB/DataBase;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=user_name;PASSWORD=user_password" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -o Data
```

> Error: listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

user'y выданы все привилегии и гранты, в sqlplus вход нормальный

не могу понять в чём ошибка

Версия Oracle - 21.3.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)))/test
```

Кому интересно, нашёл ответ, замените Data Source на тот, что выше